# foreachBatch() not printing results in databricks in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to print the results of a streamingQuery in databricks but i think from what i have seen it is not really possible, so instead i write the data in memory and try to query the stream directly. The code is this:

```py
def foreach_batch_function(df, batchId):
    rows_inserted = streamQuery.recentProgress[-1]['numInputRows']
    
    q = f"""
        select * from streaming_query
        ORDER BY monitor_ts_utc DESC LIMIT {rows_inserted}
        """
    try:
        spark.sql(q).show()
    except Exception:
        pass


rateDf = (spark
      .readStream
      .format("delta")
      .load("dbfs:/mnt/etc/etc/table_to_monitor")
      .select("server_name", "task_name", "monitor_ts_utc"))


streamQuery = (rateDf
               .writeStream
               .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function)
               .format("memory")
               .queryName('streaming_query')
               .outputMode("append")
               .start())
```

With `foreachBatch` i try to query the stream and get the last number of rows inserted but no result is printed.
I also tried to use `awaitTermination()` in the end of the streamQuery but if it is set without and int value the `streamQuery` never starts.

If anyone has more info about these i would also like to ask some extra questions because i am just learning about spark streaming and i am hard stuck. Or please point me in a course that doesn't just follow spark documentation as most courses i found do this.

First time posting here so if i did not follow some rule exactly please don't roast me much.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to print a content of it?

Comment: I am in the stage of learning and it would be really helpful if i could see what and how data is going in and of the stream as i do joins or transformation in general

Comment: use `display` function instead

Comment: is writestream supported by display because i can't seem to make it work.

Comment: yes, it's supported - try `display(rateDf)`

Comment: Thank you for the info, but it is not what i am asking, and display does not work with writestream, unless i am doing something wrong.

display(streamQuery) just prints this:
<pyspark.sql.streaming.query.StreamingQuery at 0x7f2dfe471f40>

Comment: You don’t need writestream with display - just pass a dataframe to it

Comment: I see, i get what you say now. Thank you a lot! Can i message you in some other platform if you have the time to give me some tips? It is totally fine if you don't have the time though.

Comment: Best is to ask questions here. Or you can ask them on databricks community forum